# The most complete reference for identities and special values for polylogarithm and polygamma functions

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, gamma-function, polylogarithm, polygamma

I am looking for a book, paper, web site, etc. (or several ones) containing the most complete list of identities and special values for the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) $\operatorname{Li}_s(z)$ and [polygamma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) $\psi^{(a)}(z)$ functions, including [generalizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygamma_function) to negative, non-integer and complex orders and arguments.

As far as I know, there is an ongoing research in this area, and many new and curious identities occur from time to time. Here is the list of resources I found so far:

- [Dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilogarithm) at *Wikipedia*
- [Dilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) at *MathWorld*
- [PolyLog](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01) at *The Wolfram Functions Site*
- [Trilogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html)  at *MathWorld*
- [Polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) at *Wikipedia*
- [Digamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) at *Wikipedia*
- [Digamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) at *MathWorld*
- [Trigamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html) at *MathWorld*
- [PolyGamma](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma2/03/ShowAll.html) at *The Wolfram Functions Site*

Comment: Anatol Kirillov, Dilogarithm identities, available from http://arxiv.org/abs/hep--th/9408113

Comment: Dear Vladimir, I see you are also interested in the polylogarithm function. Are you willing to discuss some topics related to it? For instance I have the following question on its connection with Bernoulli polynomials.: [Connection between the polylogarithm and the Bernoulli polynomials.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4862815/622884)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#ii) cites Lewin (1981), Kölbig (1986), Maximon (2003), Prudnikov et al. which can be found in the bibliography of Dlmf.

Answer (score 15):

My preferred books on the topics

Lewin L. *Polylogarithms and associated functions* (NH, 1981)

Lewin L. (ed.) *Structural properties of polylogarithms* (AMS, 1991)

H. M. Srivastava, Choi Junesang, *Zeta and q-Zeta Functions and Associated Series and Integrals*. (Elsevier,2011)

Comment: Thanks! Both answers are useful, so I decided to accept the first one, but award the bounty to yours. Hopefully, it does not feel unfair to anyone.

Comment: [Lewin book price: $\large\$\ \color{#c00000}{599.95}$ !!!](http://www.amazon.com/Polylogarithms-Associated-Functions-Leonard-Lewin/dp/0444005501)

Comment: @FelixMarin at least it's not $600!