# Find $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Mathematica gives:
$$S= -\frac{1}{12}\pi^2\log(2)+\frac{\log(2)^3}{6}+ \frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$$ 
How can I prove it?

Comment: Complex analysis seems the way!

Comment: _You_ can't prove it, obviously. Look for identities and special values of polylogarithm (trilogarithm, in this case), cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555961/the-most-complete-reference-for-identities-and-special-values-for-polylogarithm

Comment: @vidyarthi I don't see how.

Comment: Why is it obvious, @professorvector?

Comment: I guess you asked how to prove that, because you don't know. If that's wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Let $$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n^3}.$$

Then

$$f'(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n^2},$$

$$(xf'(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n},$$

$$(x(xf'(x))')'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}=\frac1{1-x}.$$

Now backward, integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$$(xf'(x))'=\frac{\log(1-x)}x,$$

$$f'(x)=\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{\log(1-x)}xdx,$$

$$f(x)=\int_0^x\left[\frac1x\int_0^x\frac{\log(1-x)}xdx\right]dx.$$

Comment: but we require complex analysis to evaluate $\int_0^x\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx$ isnt it?

Comment: I don't think the integrals here can be easily evaluated because if they could be, then $lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}f(x)$ would give $\zeta(3)$, and this solves an open problem. Right?

Comment: @Asemismaiel: maybe Ramanujan... :)

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{n^3}=\text{Li}_3(x)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function. Have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) for special values; in your case, $x=\frac 12$.

Comment: Your link gives $\text{Li}_3(x)= -\frac{1}{12}\pi^2\log(2)+\frac{\log(2)^3}{6}+ \frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$ and it says that it can be evaluated analytically but it doesn't tell me how. I'm asking for a derivation.